# How to keep biryani hot and moist for a long time

Tags: meat, flavor, rice, spicy-hot

I am looking forward to opening a biryani stall in my area, but my supplier of prepared biryani is far away. What method can I adopt to keep biryani rice fluffy, moist and hot for longer period of time? I want to keep it hot in a prepared condition for eight hours.

Comment: I think trying to keep food warm for a long time (8 hours) is very difficult (food safety and "fluffy and moist")
I would check with local regulations in regards to handling warm food.

Comment: Are you transporting it for 8 hours or keeping it in one location?

Answer (score 4):

**A Holding Cabinet**

I'm assuming by your supplier being far away, you mean you can only get a delivery once per day. Keeping food overnight and then serving it all day is probably unfeasible.

While 8 hours might be a stretch, it sounds like your best bet would be a warmer cabinet. [Here's](https://www.hatcocorp.com/en/equipment/cabinets/holding-cabinets/flav-r-savor-portable-energy-efficient-holding-cabinet-fshc-7wx-ee) an example. They're temperature and humidity controlled.

> The Hatco Flav-R-Savor® Portable Energy Efficient Holding Cabinet is capable of holding an array of hot foods at optimum serving temperatures for extended periods of time, saving you money through increased energy efficiencies, and allows for advanced preparation ahead of peak-serving periods.

Comment: Totally. A holding cabinet that is capable of holding the rice at a temperature which prevents the growth of Bacillus Cereus is the *only* safe solution.